# Normal order vs Applicative order in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I got this program:

```
(define a 2)

(define (goo x)
  (display x) (newline)
  (lambda (y) (/ x y)))

(define (foo x)
  (let ((f (goo a)))
    (if (= x 0)
        x
        (f x))))
```

and I asked to compare the evaluation results between the applicative and normal order on the expression `(foo (foo 0))`.

As I know, in applicative order, `(display x)` in function `goo` will print `x` and after it the program will collapse because `y` isn't defined. But when I run it in Scheme nothing happens. What is the reason?

Comment: "But when I run it in Scheme nothing happens." What Scheme? In Chicken Scheme `(foo (foo 0))` prints 2 2 and returns 0 . Why do you think it is a problem with application order vs. normal order?

Answer (score 2):

`(foo 0)` evaluates to this code:

```
(define (goo 2)
  (display 2) (newline)
  (lambda (y) (/ 2 y)))

(define (foo x)
  (let ((f (goo 2)))
    (if (= 0 0)
        0
        ((lambda (y) (/ 2 y)) 0))))
```

and prints `2`, returning `0`. While `(foo 4)` evaluates to:

```
(define (goo 2)
  (display 2) (newline)
  (lambda (y) (/ 2 y)))

(define (foo 4)
  (let ((f (goo 2)))
    (if (= 4 0)
        4
        ((lambda (y) (/ 2 y)) 4))))
```

and prints `2`, returning `0.5`.

Comment: Thanks, but what the difference between applicative order and Normal order? because when I run it in scheme - nothing happen.

Comment: @Eyal: See [Applicative order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Applicative_order) and [Normal order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Normal_order) on Wikipedia, and appropriate sections in SICP: [Evaluating Combinations](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/chapter1/node5.html) and [The Substitution Model for Procedure Application](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/chapter1/node7.html). Scheme and most programming languages use applicative order of evaluation.

Comment: applicative order: left-most innermost in scheme . check http://web.mit.edu/6.827/www/old/lectures/L04-LambdaLetPrint.pdf